# Positive homogeneous norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

Is every positive homogeneous Minkowski norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ equivalent to the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Here by positive homogeneity, we mean the condition 2. (absolute homogeneity) of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics) is replaced with
$$
p(sx)=sp(x)
$$
for every $s>0$ and for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

A positive homogeneous Minkowski norm as defined on Page 4 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.05467.pdf

I know for a norm this is true, but not sure for positive homogeneous Minkowski norm.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^n$ all norms are equivalent, that is, all maps ||•||$:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ satisfying the triangle inequality, $||\lambda \cdot x||=|\lambda|\cdot||x||$ for all $\lambda, x$ and $||x||=0$ iff $x=0$. You mean that instead of this second condition you wish to weaken it to only work for positive numbers?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: In that case, I think I may have an answer. Please give me some time to finish writing the details.

Comment: Thanks. I also edited the question a little.

Answer (score 0):

I think they will be equivalent. Let me explain my reasoning, which also works in the more general case of two functions positively homogeneous and subadditive functions $p$, $q$ satisfying $p(x)=0$ iff $x=0$ and $q(x)=0$ iff $q=0$ (why a positively homogeneous Minkowski norm is one such function is explained below; note that the Euclidean norm also satisfies all 3 properties).

Altough now in retrospective a proof can probably be writen in terms of just algebraic manipulations, to gain intuition I tried to interpret the question geometrically. As for why this may be a plausible idea, you might want to read about [Minkowski functionals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_functional). To answer this question we will not be building one but we will be isolating the properties our maps' unit balls satisfy due to their nice algebraic properties, which Minkowski functionals nicely relate. Allow me to elaborate just a little bit further: if $p$ is a Minkowski functioal associted to an open, convex set $0\in U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ then you will have that $U=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n | \, p(x)< 1\}$, and "conversely" the Minkowski functional associated to a seminorm's or norm's unit ball is itself. The map $p$ will satisfy good algebraic properties as $U$ has good geometric properties, and vice versa. Let's explore how these ideas may be useful to answer the question you posed.

## Informal sketch of the proof

If you have two positively-homogeneous subadditive functions $p,q$ which satisfy that $p(x)=0$ iff $x=0$ and $q(x)=0$ iff $x=0$ then the (open) unit balls associated to each map will satisfy that they are bounded, (absorbent,) open, (convex) and have $0$ as a member. In $\mathbb{R}^n$ we will always be able to, given two bounded open sets $V, W$ having $0$ as a member, shrink $V$ enough by scaling by a positive number so that $\lambda \cdot V\subseteq W$. Reasoning this way with $p$ and $q$'s unit balls will allow us to prove that they are topologically equivalent, and then equivalent in the same way that norms are equivalent.

**Edit: Adding the relevant information from the comments to the answer:**

The positive homogeneous Minkowski norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ mentioned in the paper cited is a function $F$ that in said paper is said to be strictly convex, positively homogeneous and satisfying $F(x)>0$ if $x\neq 0$ in preposition 2.1. These properties suffice to show that $F$ is subadditive, positively homogeneous and that $F$ satisfies $F(x)=0$ iff $x=0$. One way to show so is the following one:

- $F(0) = F(0\cdot e_1)=0\cdot F(e_1)=0$ and so $F(0)=0$, which combined with $F(x)>0$ for $x\neq 0$ gives the third property, and
- if $x\neq y$, then by strict convexity we have that:
  $$\frac{1}{2}F(x+y) = F(\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2}y)<\frac{1}{2}F(x)
     + \frac{1}{2}F(y)=\frac{1}{2}(F(x)+F(y))$$ and if $x=y$ by positive homogeneiety $F(x+y)=2F(x)=F(x)+F(y)$ and we have that $F$ is subadditive.

## Filling in the details

Let's then prove $p$ and $q$ unit balls' necessary properties. I will show them for $p$, and the reasoning for $q$ is analogous.

1. $p$'s unit ball will be open if $p$ is continuous as it is $p^{-1}(-\infty, 1)$. $p$ is a continuous map because it is continuous at $0$, and to prove it is continuous elsewhere one can extend it from there. Note that:
   $$p(x)\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_i|\cdot p(\text{sign}(x_i) e_i)\leq \max_{1\leq i \leq n} \{p(e_i), p(-e_i)\}\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_i|= \max_{1\leq i \leq n} \{p(e_i), p(-e_i)\}\cdot||x||_1$$
   and then continuity at 0 follows. Then since $p$ is sub-additive we have that:
   $$|p(x)-p(y)|\leq p(x-y)\leq \max_{1\leq i \leq n} \{p(e_i), p(-e_i)\} ||x-y||_1$$
   from which (uniform) continuity follows.
2. As $p$ is continuous, $p(S_1^{||•||_2}(0))$ is compact and thus since $p$ does not take the value $0$ in the unit sphere then this set has a non-zero minimum $m$. This means that $p$'s unit ball is contained in $\overline{B}_{\frac{1}{m}}^{||•||_2}(0)$ and is then bounded. That is, if $x$ is non-zero then $\frac{x}{||x||_2}$ is in the unit sphere so $p\left(\frac{x}{||x||_2}\right)\geq m$ and $p(x)\geq m\cdot ||x||_2$. Then if $p(x)<1$ we have that $m\cdot ||x||_2<1$ and $||x||_2<\frac{1}{m}$ as we claimed.
3. $0$ is a member of $p$'s unit ball immediately from $p$'s properties.

This proves that $p$'s unit ball is open, has $0$ as a member and is bounded.

Let's now show that any two open and bounded neighbourhoods of $0$ $V$ and $W$ satisfy that there exists a positive $\lambda$ such that $\lambda V \subseteq W$. Since $V$ is bounded, there is a ball $B_{R}(0)$ such that $V\subseteq B_{R}(0)$, and since $W$ is a neighborhood of 0 there exists another ball $B_{r}(0)$ such that $0\in B_{r}(0)\subseteq W$. Now choose $0<\lambda<\frac{r}{R}$ and $\lambda \cdot V \subseteq W$ as we wished to prove.

Applying this to $p$ and $q$'s unit balls gives us that there exists $\lambda>0$ such that if $p(x)<1$, then $q(\lambda\cdot x)<1$. Then $q(\frac{\lambda\cdot \delta}{p(x)}x)<1$ for every non-zero $x$ and every $\delta\in (0,1)$ and then $q(x)\leq \frac{1}{\lambda \cdot \delta}\cdot p(x)$ for every $x$. We can proceed similarly to get the other inequality we need. We can let $\delta$ go to 1 to obtain then $q(x)\leq \frac{1}{\lambda}\cdot p(x)$. Then we can proceed similarly to get an inequality in the other direction, and combine them both to obtain the desired result. That is, if $q(x)\leq \frac{1}{\lambda}p(x)$ and $p(x)\leq \frac{1}{\mu}q(x)$ for every $x$ for some positive constants $\lambda, \mu$, $\mu \cdot p(x) \leq q(x) \leq \frac{1}{\lambda} p(x)$ for every $x$ as we wished to prove.

I highly recommend sketching the drawings of the unit balls involved in order to get the geometric intuition behind these ideas.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I would be very grateful if you kindly post a clear proof.

Comment: Yes, I decided to post the idea first but I have now filled in more of the details since it would take some time. Please tell me if there is something else I should clarify or write in more detail.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will look at it more carefully. Just to make sure, you posted the answer for positive homogeneous Minkowski norm as defined on page 4 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.05467.pdf ?

Comment: What I have proved in that answer is that any two subadditive, positively homogeneous functions $p$, $q$ that satisfy $p(x)=0$ iff $x=0$ and $q(x)=0$ iff $x=0$ are equivalent in the sense that there exist positive constants $C, D$ such that $C\cdot p(x)\leq q(x) \leq D\cdot p(x)$. The euclidean norm satisfies those 3 properties. In the paper you mentioned the only property they don't explicitly say that $F$ has is subadditivity. However, this property is only used to prove that $p$ is continuous here, and since $F$ is smooth we don't need to use it. Is  this good enough? Please let me know.

Comment: Thanks. But please note that $F$ is not mentioned to be continuous at $0$ in the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.05467.pdf. Kindly let me know.

Comment: Since $F$ is positively homogeneous, $F(0) = F(0\cdot 
 e_1)=0\cdot F(e_1)=0$. Then we have that $F$ is continuous at $0$ using that $F(B_1(0))$ is bounded from above (and below) so because of positive homogeneiety if $M$ is its maximum we have that if $\varepsilon>0$ then $F(B_{\frac{\varepsilon}{2M}}(0))\subseteq \frac{\varepsilon}{2M} F(B_1(0))\subseteq \frac{\varepsilon}{2M}B_{2M}(0)\subseteq B_{\varepsilon}(0)$. Thanks, you are right that something needed to be said about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will go through the proof carefully and let you know if I cannot understand something.

Comment: In the paper they mention that $F$ is strictly convex. Then we have that: $$\frac{1}{2}F(x+y) = F(\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2}y)<\frac{1}{2}F(x) + \frac{1}{2}F(y)=\frac{1}{2}(F(x)+F(y))$$ so $F$ was subadditive after all, and there is no need to make a different proof for the positive homogeneous Minkowski norm :). I will soon edit the answer to clarify this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139507/discussion-between-nicolas-agote-and-mathguide).

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. If I understand correctly, it seems your answer in point 1 and point 2 give the equivalence of $p$ with the Euclidean norm, since $\|x\|_2$ and $\|x\|_1$ are equivalent.

Comment: True, you're right!

Comment: I'll edit the answer to add this insight. The rest of the proof is similar to a way in which one can prove any two norms are equivalent and is a way to show that any two maps $p$, $q$ that satisfy the relevant conditions are equivalent, but it's technically not needed here. Re-reading the end of the proof it seems like a way to think geometrically about what does it mean for both $p$ and $q$ to be equivalent to the $2$-norm, but a more algebraic proof could have been written instead then in retrospective.